# Jquery append() and appendTo() append multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying a defer load for google maps, it should load when a modal is triggered:

```
$( document ).on( "shown.bs.modal", function(){
        $script = $("<script>", {'type': 'text/javascript', 'src': 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initialize'});
        $script.appendTo($("head"));
});
```

but I got multiple scripts line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&amp;callback=initialize"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&amp;callback=initialize"></script>
```

Console:

```
 You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.main.js:59 klmain.js:60 (anonymous function)js?signed_in=true&callback=initialize&_=1424619719408:21 google.maps.Loadmain.js:60 (anonymous function)main.js:61 (anonymous function)
```

how I get append only one line?
or is there another way to do it (jquery)?

thanks very much.
Salu2

Comment: You can check if script already in head not append

Comment: Did yo check whether shown.bs.modal Event is fired more than ones.

Comment: because a need a defer load (goal: optimization)

Comment: @Blauharley  shown.bs.modal is fired one time, I checked with a console.log

Comment: It's only a question but you do not have got more than one head-tag, do you?

Comment: You should provide concrete sample to replicate your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check if `google.maps` is already available, when it does run `initialize`, otherwise load the API:

```
$( document ).on( "shown.bs.modal", function(){
   if(window.google && window.google.maps){
     initialize();
     return;
   }
        $script = $("<script>", 
                    {'type': 'text/javascript', 
                     'src': 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initialize'});
        $script.appendTo($("head"));
});
```

Comment: It's works!!! you're great!!!
now, why "shown.bs.modal" is fired when page had loaded? it no sense.

Comment: `shown.bs.modal` will fire each time you open a bootstrap-modal. I guess you want to draw a map in a modal, so on the first modal you must load the API, on further modals you only need to draw the map(the API is already loaded).

Comment: But when you don't want to draw a map in a modal `shown.bs.modal` isn't the appropriate event